# How to search date from certain date onwards

Tags: postgresql

I want to show all dates onward when searching dates. For eg. i searched 2012-12-24, all dates going forward will appear.

Here's my query right now that can search the exact date only and not including date onward.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
where cast(u.start_date as varchar) = '2012-12-24'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an inequality:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user u
WHERE u.start_date >= '2012-12-24';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I need the cast since I'm converting the date to string(varchar) :( sry im just a beginner

Comment: No...do not convert the date column to text, just compare to a valid date literal.